# A closed subspace of Hilbert sapce

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space, $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a countable orthonormal system in $H$.  $V$ is a subspace of $H$, 
>   $$V:=\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne_n: \sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n|^2<\infty\}$$
>   Show that $V$ is closed.

Suppose that $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequecne in $V$ that converges to a limit $x$, it's suffice to show the limit  $x$ is also in $V$. Since $x_n\in V$ for $n=1,2,\cdots$, one can write $x_n$ as the form $$x_n=\sum_{m=1}^\infty c_{nm}e_m\quad (n=1,2,\cdots).$$ Now the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $x$, thus $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence, it follows that $(c_{nm})_{n=1}^\infty$ is also a Cahcuy sequence for every $m=1,2,\cdots$, thus converges to a limit $c_m$, I want to show $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $\sum_{m=1}^\infty c_me_m$, but I can't complete it.

Comment: Do you know/can you prove that $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is a Hilbert space?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, I get it, $V$ is complete hence closed.

Comment: Effectively, what you are trying to prove is exactly that $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is complete. (No surprise, since a subspace of a complete Hausdorff space is closed if and only if it is complete.)